# Counting row per column when upload excel with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter

I want to upload the data excel, but before it uploads the data I want to make sure these data first. example: there is one blank column if it can not be uploaded. The simple question, how do I count the number of rows of each column that has been uploaded earlier?

so later the output will be like this:

Column 1: 50 lines
Column 2: 49 lines. for example (assuming empty 1 data)
Column 3: 47 lines. for example (assuming empty 3 data)

Here is my controller

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $data['numRows']; $i++) {                            
    if($data['cells'][$i][1] == '') break;
    $kode=str_replace($simbol, '', $data['cells'][$i][1]);
    $dataexcel[$i-1]['kode_matkul'] = $kode;
    $dataexcel[$i-1]['nama_matkul'] = $data['cells'][$i][2];
    $dataexcel[$i-1]['sks_a'] = $data['cells'][$i][3];
    $dataexcel[$i-1]['sks_b'] = $data['cells'][$i][3];
    $dataexcel[$i-1]['semester_matkul'] = $data['cells']$i][4];                                        
}
```

I try use `echo count($data['cells'][$i][1])`
but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you asking how to push in the amount of columns that were observed and not empty into an array stack and reference that array stack later?

Comment: Yes, I want to insert data from excel , but I want to check it first whether data in all row is not empty with counting each data in each column

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an array to hold the count of the empty cells. This can be done using a simple single array.

```
$emptyValues = array_fill(1,$data['num_rows'],0) ; //create array of predefined length and set all valuese to 0.

for ($i = 1; $i <= $data['numRows']; $i++) {                            
if($data['cells'][$i][1] == '') {
     $emptyValues[$i]++ ;
     break;
}
$kode=str_replace($simbol, '', $data['cells'][$i][1]);
$dataexcel[$i-1]['kode_matkul'] = $kode;
$dataexcel[$i-1]['nama_matkul'] = $data['cells'][$i][2];
$dataexcel[$i-1]['sks_a'] = $data['cells'][$i][3];
$dataexcel[$i-1]['sks_b'] = $data['cells'][$i][3];
$dataexcel[$i-1]['semester_matkul'] = $data['cells']$i][4];
```

}

The `$emptyValues` would be something like

```
[
    1 => 0,
    2 => 1, //2nd column, 1 empty cell
    3 => 3
];
```

The above is untested btw